# ASP MVC 5 project start without debugging extremely slow

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I use Visual Studio's default ASP.NET WEB Application MVC template to create a demo project, which contains 100 tables, each table contains 100 fields by code first method, the strange thing is

if i use the MVC template without Authentication, everything is fine, using start without debugging(ctrl+F5) to launch the project cost around 10s

if I use the MVC template WITH Authentication, using start without debugging(ctrl+F5) to launch the project cost several minutes, even if i manually remove all the Authentication related reference and codes, it still cost several minutes

if i use the MVC template without Authentication, then manually add the Authentication, using start without debugging(ctrl+F5) to launch the project cost around 10s

so any tips? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You  must have used Entity Framework. So, it will take time at the first load. When its load, it wont take much time afterwards.
The thing is, entity framwork takes time to initialize all the class objects. So, Its obvious dont worry. I think EF 6 has reduced this time. Hope it helps you.

Comment: thanks for your reply Pratik Bhoir, actually i used same 100 tables, each table contains 100 fields on MVC template WITH Authentication and MVC template WITHOUT Authentication, why the time cost difference is so big?